# angular UI router | $stateParams not working

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

seems like `$stateParams` is not working.
passing date like this:

```
$state.go('state2', { someParam : 'broken magic' });
```

params being ignored on the target state

```
console.log('state2 params:', $stateParams); // return empty object {}
```

**code:**

```
    var app = angular.module('app', [
     'ui.router'
    ]);

    app.config(function($stateProvider) {
      $stateProvider
            .state('state1', {
                url: '',
                templateUrl: 'state-1.html',
                controller : function ($scope, $state, $stateParams) {
                  $scope.go = function () {
                    $state.go('state2', { someParam : 'broken magic' });
                  };

                  console.log('state1 params:', $stateParams);
                }
            })
            .state('state2', {
                url: 'state2',
                templateUrl: 'state-2.html',
                controller : function ($scope, $state, $stateParams) {
                  $scope.go = function () {
                    $state.go('state1', { someOtherParam : 'lazy lizard' });
                  };

                  console.log('state2 params:', $stateParams);
                }
            });
    });
```

**Live example can be found [here](http://jsbin.com/weger/5/edit)**

thank you.

Comment: The example doesn't work for me.

Comment: How did you define your states? (Show us the `$stateProvider` part).

Comment: @kba, I updated my question to make it more clear.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

You can't pass arbitrary parameters between states, you need to have them defined as part of your `$stateProvider` definition. E.g.

```
$stateProvider
    .state('contacts.detail', {
        url: "/contacts/:contactId",
        templateUrl: 'contacts.detail.html',
        controller: function ($stateParams) {
            console.log($stateParams);
        }
    }) ...
```

The above will output an object with the contactId property defined. If you go to `/contacts/42`, your `$stateParams` will be `{contactId: 42}`.

See the [documentation for UI-Router URL Routing](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing) for more information.

Comment: @nilskp Yes, that sucks, but you should rarely need it anyway; all your data should belong in your services/factories/providers. In AngularJS 2.0, I think they'll make arbitrary parameter passing possible.

Comment: I don't know. I prefer parameter passing over global state.

Comment: I just encountered this issue too and it seems to be an arbitrary restriction in ui-router: http://bit.ly/1qbkhRq

Comment: @nilskp I'm not saying you shouldn't use parameter passing. I'm saying when you do, it should be registered in the route. Going to a specific page with an ID? Add it to the url. Going to show an error message? Don't put it in the url—you don't want people linking to it anyway.

Comment: I'd like to pass actual state, not just a text string. Kinda hard to do in a URL.

Answer (score 54):

if you don't want to define your parameter in the url, you must include a params property on the state you are transitioning to. Otherwise the data will be removed from the $stateParams object. The format of the params object is an array of strings in older versions of angular-ui-router; in newer versions it is an object of empty objects:

```
params: { id: {}, blue: {}}
```

See this example:

```
$stateProvider.state('state1', {
    url: '',
    params: {
        id: 0,
        blue: ''
    },
    templateUrl: 'state-1.html',
    controller: function($scope, $state, $stateParams) {
        $scope.go = function() {
            $state.go('state2', {
                id: 5,
                blue: '#0000FF'
            });
        };

        console.log('state params:', $stateParams);
    }
});
```

Related question:
[Parameters for states without URLs in ui-router for AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22814554/parameters-for-states-without-urls-in-ui-router-for-angularjs)

Comment: This was exactly what I needed--hidden parameters that are not displayed in the URL. I have been searching for a couple of days now, and have not been able to find this in the UI-Router docs. Thank you so much!

Comment: http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$stateProvider#state

Comment: NOTE: (on v0.2.10) If the state is a child state of a parent that has a URL parameter, then that parameter needs to be included in the `params` array.

Comment: This syntax will not work for newer versions. You need to declare it like this now `params: { someParam: {} }`. Source : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22814554/parameters-for-states-without-urls-in-ui-router-for-angularjs The documentation still states it should be an array which is wrong and very confusing.

Comment: FYI The empty objects `blue: {}` you're passing are treated as the default values.  So pass `blue: null` instead if you're doing something like `if ($stateParams.blue) ...` in your controller.

Comment: This was the syntax I was looking for, thanks, enjoy the bounty.

Comment: Thank you!! You saved my day!! i solved it by adding params key in destination state .

Answer (score 6):

Just passing parameters to a state is not enough. You have to define the parameter explicitly by name in the `url` property of your state.

If you don't do this, ui-router won't know this state is expecting a parameter and the `$stateParams` object will not be populated like you want.

Here is an example of how you might modify your state to expect a parameter, inject `$stateParams`, and do something with said parameter:

```
$stateProvider.state('state1', {
        url: '',
        templateUrl: 'state-1.html',
        controller : function ($scope, $state, $stateParams) {
          $scope.params = $stateParams;
          $scope.go = function () {
            $state.go('state2', { id : 'broken magic' });
          };

          console.log('state1 params:', $stateParams);
        }
    })

    .state('state2', {
            url: 'state2/:id',
            templateUrl: 'state-2.html',
            controller : function ($scope, $state, $stateParams) {
              $scope.params = $stateParams;
              $scope.go = function () {
                $state.go('state1', { someOtherParam : 'lazy lizard' });
              };

              console.log('state2 params:', $stateParams);
            }
        })
```

[Here is a working example of passing state params on jsfiddle.](http://jsbin.com/kijonixi/2/edit)

Answer (score 2):

the solutions above works but for my case I needed to pass query parameter so I dit it like this:

```
$stateProvider
        .state('state1', {
            url: '/state1?other',
            templateUrl: 'state-1.html',
            controller : function ($scope, $state, $stateParams) {
              $scope.params = $stateParams;
              $scope.go = function () {
                $state.go('state2', { someParam : 'broken magic' });
              };

              console.log('state1 params:', $stateParams);
            }
        })
        .state('state2', {
            url: '/state2?someParam',
            templateUrl: 'state-2.html',
            controller : function ($scope, $state, $stateParams) {
              $scope.params = $stateParams;
              $scope.go = function () {
                $state.go('state1', { other : 'lazy lizard' });
              };

              console.log('state2 params:', $stateParams);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

Make a transport and use it!

```
angular_app.factory('$$transport', function($q) {
    var transport;
    return transport = {
        dfr: $q.defer(),
        push: function(v) {
            return transport.dfr.resolve(v);
        },
        then: function(s, f) {
            if (f == null) {
                f = function() {};
            }
            return transport.dfr.promise.then(function(_s) {
                s(_s);
                transport.dfr = $q.defer();
                return transport.then(s, f);
            }, function(_f) {
                f(_f);
                transport.dfr = $q.defer();
                return transport.then(s, f);
            });
        }
    };
});
$stateProvider.state('state1', {
            url: '/state1?other',
            templateUrl: 'state-1.html',
            controller : function ($scope, $state, $$transport) {
              $$transport.then(function(s) {
                $scope.param = s
                console.log('state1 params:', s);
              });
              $scope.go = function () {
                $state.go('state2', { someParam : 'broken magic' });
              }
            }
        })
        .state('state2', {
            url: '/state2?someParam',
            templateUrl: 'state-2.html',
            controller : function ($scope, $state, $$transport) {
              $scope.go = function () {
                $$transport.push({other:'lazy lizard'});
                $state.go('state1');
              };
            }
        });
```

Comment: What is a transport and what is $$transport? Please provide some documentation. Thank you.

Comment: $$ should not be used. There are better solutions.