# Parameters for states without URLs in ui-router for AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am using ui-router to represent states in my AngularJS app. In it I'd like to change the state without changing the URL (basically a "detail view" is updated but this should not affect the URL).

I use `<a ui-sref="item.detail({id: item.id})">` to display the detail but this only works if I specify a URL like `url: "/detail-:id"` in my `$stateProvider`.

It seems to me that the current state is only defined through the URL.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Thanks for your answer, it did help me in the right direction but I'd just like to add a more complete description.

In my specific issue there was a complicating factor because the state I needed to inject a non-URL parameter to was a child state. That complicated things slightly.

The `params: ['id']` part goes in the `$stateProvider` declaration like this:

```
$stateProvider.state('parent', {
    url: '/:parentParam',
    templateUrl: '...',
    controller: '...'
}).
state('parent.child', {
    params: ['parentParam','childParam'],
    templateUrl: '...',
    controller: '...'
});
```

And the param name is connected to the `ui-sref` attribute like this:

```
<a ui-sref=".child({ childParam: 'foo' })">
```

And the catch is this:

> If the parent state also has a URL parameter then the child **needs**
>   to also declare that in its `params` array. In the example above "parentParam" must be included in the childstate.

If you don't do that then a module-error will be thrown when the application is initialized. This is at least true on the latest version at the time of writing (v.0.2.10).

**EDIT**

@gulsahkandemir points out that

> Declaration of params in a state definition has changed to params: {
>   id: {} } from params: ['id']

Judging by the changelog, this seems to be the case starting from v0.2.11

Details of params [can be found in the official docs](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$stateProvider)

Comment: I'm trying this out on v0.2.11 and I get a module-error even though parentParam has been added to the list of params. Thoughts?

Comment: @PrathanThananart Depends on what the error is. I had to set chrome devtools to break on all exceptions to find out what was wrong. The error that ended up in the console didn't tell me anything useful.

Comment: Just vanilla module-error like you'd get if you forget to include a parentParam. I had the same experience as yours—the stack trace was useless and when I downgraded to 0.2.10, it started working perfectly. Hope this helps someone.

Comment: Check gulsahkandemir's answer also.

Comment: Seems that params returned being an object: `params: { id: null }`

Comment: `If the parent state also has a URL parameter then the child needs to also declare that in its params array. In the example above "parentParam" must be included in the childstate.` Just a heads up I am using version 1.4.1 and in my child state I did NOT have to declare parent params.

Comment: Yeah, it's reasonable to assume some things changed between v0.2.10 and v.1.4.1

Comment: I send params using `$state.go('state1.name', {name: 'ram', id: '123'})`
now I want to show url is like `/home/ram` in the state called `'state2.name'`
and I want to use `id` in the `'state2.name'` controller. The above answer is not working. what should I do?

Answer (score 46):

Just an additional information for new comers to this post:

Declaration of params in a state definition has changed to `params: { id: {} }` from `params: ['id']`

So be aware :)

Source: http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$stateProvider

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I edited that piece of information into my answer and I hope you don't mind. This change seems to have been introduced in 0.2.11, is that something you can confirm?

Answer (score 10):

I now figured out, that you need to use the `params: ['id']` property of the state in order to have the key not stripped when not using a URL.