# Angularjs ui-router - pass extras 'unplanned' parameters

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have this simple state :

```
.state('search', {
    url: '/search',
    templateUrl: 'views/search.html',
    controller: 'search'
})
```

And I would like to pass any extra **unplanned** parameters to the controller when using `search` state or `/search` route :

```
ui-sref="search({foo:1, bar:2})" 
// would call '#/search?foo=1&bar2', 
// match the state and pass foo and bar to the controller (through $stateParams)
```

When I try this, it matches the otherwise of the router instead. :(

I've read a lot of solutions that imply to declare each parameter in the state:

```
.state('search', {
    url: '/search?param1&param2&param3?...',
})
```

But I cannot do this as far as the parameters list is not really defined and changes all the time depending on searched content.

Is there a way to achieve this ? Or am I wrong somewhere ?

Thx.

---

**EDIT** : When I try to call directly this url : `#/search?foo=1`, the state `search` matches but the `foo` parameter never goes to $stateParams which is empty. I don't know how to get it in.

Comment: Maybe you can pass `search({query: {foo: 1, bar: 2, baz: 3, ...}})`, so that query will always be filled and contains as many parameters as you need

Comment: @clement_frndz It almost did the trick. I got `query: '[Object object]'`. But the idea was good. I thought my need was something pretty obvious... Don't know how to success...

Comment: Seems like this feature is not available. https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/539. Here is a work around some used to overcome this, it might help you https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/539.

Comment: What's the problem if you got the query object in $stateParams ? Is it empty ?

Comment: @clement_frndz It is not an object. It is a string saying "[Object object]"... ;)

Comment: @cubbuk Thx for the link. I will give a try to this and tell.

Comment: @cubbuk I finally can't get through this :( The workaround did not work for me. I will have to think about something different. Thx anyway.

Answer (score -1):

```
.state('search', {
   params: ['param1','param2','param3'],
   templateUrl: '...',
   controller: '...'
});

ui-sref="search({param1:1, param2:2})"
```

Credit goes to [Parameters for states without URLs in ui-router for AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22814554/parameters-for-states-without-urls-in-ui-router-for-angularjs)