# ui router: change stateParams from service?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am trying to save a few of my variables in url so that my web app is stateless.

Right now what I am trying to do is:

```
$AppService.setMyVar = function(myVar){
    $state.params.myVar = myVar; //myVar = 1234
}
```

And I expect my url which is configured like `/contact?myVar=` to change from `/contact` to `/contact?myVar=1234`

How do I do this in angular?
Also, can I access variables set in my url like this?

```
$AppService.getMyVar = function(){
    return $state.params.myVar;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Syntax should use `$stateParams` .. You will need to inject the `$stateParams` service into your controller to access the properties, like so:

```
controller: function ($stateParams) {
        console.log($stateParams);
    }
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/22611182/1516309

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing#stateparams-service

Comment: Thanks for the update, I figured out that a quick way to implement what I wanted was to create a wrapper method for `$state.go`. So controller first call some setters in my service and use `$AppService.go` so that params set in service are passed to $stateParams