# angularjs, uirouter - Update ng-model on controller update?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

View 1:

```
<div ng-controller="ctrl1">
    <button ng-click="goToForm ({'name':'aaa'})">
    </button>
</div>
```

ctrl1:

```
    $scope.selectedList = {
        name: ""
    };

    $scope.goToForm = function(e) {
        $scope.selectedList.name = e.name;
        $state.go('view2');
        console.log(e); // prints updated value
    };
```

View 2:

```
<div ng-controller="ctrl1">

<input
        id="name"
        name="name"
        type="text"
        ng-model="selectedList.name"
        ng-readonly="true"
/>
</div>
```

But the input box is always empty, even though to get to the view the goToForm() is called. Why doesn't it update the HTML value?
Views are changed with ui.router's $state.

Comment: What is `goToExtendedForm`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing it wrong, you are changing the `state` so you must pass the data, else you'll lose it.

```
$scope.goToForm = function(e) {
    var obj = {name: e.name};
    $state.go('view2',obj);
    console.log(e); // prints updated value
};
```

and do put one `init` function inside `ctrl1.js` which checks if there are any values passed as `$stateParam`. If there are any, assign it accordingly.

```
app.controller('ctrl1',function($stateParams){

init(); // your first line of controller

// then all your code from here

function init(){
   if($stateParams.name) {
        $scope.selectedList.name = $stateParams.name;
    }
 }

})
```

**OR** you can use `ng-init="init()"` on the `<div ng-init="init()">`

Comment: Adding $stateParam to ctrl1, throws an unknown provider 'stateParamProvider' error

Comment: console.log($stateParams); in init() returns `"#": null`? The variable isnt there :S

Comment: @user3761308 because you need to define in `stateProvider` as well. check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22610787/angular-ui-router-stateparams-not-working. I think you are missing that too

Answer (score 0):

> As per your code,  wrap the default variable initialization in a method
>   and call in ng-init of view1, ignore the view2 ng-init
>
> Your controller should look as below

```
 $scope.initializeVariables=function(){
               $scope.selectedList= {name : ""} 
        }

$scope.goToForm = function(e) {
    $scope.selectedList.name = e.name;
    $state.go('view2');
    console.log(e); // prints updated value
};
```

> And view1 should include ng-init directive as below

```
<div ng-controller="ctrl1" ng-init="initializeVariables();">
    <button ng-click="goToForm ({'name':'aaa'})">
    </button>
</div>
```

Comment: @user3761308 Can you please update your 'view2' ui-router config section for more information? Also in view2 you are using  <div ng-controller="ctrl1"> that loads the entire controller ctrl1 where your code $scope.selectedList.name is set to "" with the lines  $scope.selectedList = {
        name: ""
    };

Comment: @user3761308: Updated with ng-init way